# Split value for $request_uri

Tags: nginx

In nginx I need to get all the values that are received via $request_uri and separate in several variables.

Some examples of content $resquest_uri:

http://domain.com/redirect/tx?**StatusCode=0**&**CustomParameter1=field**&**Campaign=bgrk**&**Reason=Success**

http://domain.com/redirect?**StatusCode=205**

http://domain.com/?**utm_source=ttx**

How can I separate the fields of $request_uri?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have these values in $arg_{{var}}. Check [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) out.